# Default Destructor V.S. A Simply Defined Destructor

Tags: c++, destructor, dynamic-memory-allocation

I wrote this to analyse the behavior of the destructor function of a class and its effect on memory deallocation, but the result seems to be a bit surprising to me:

```
class test {
public:
    test() {}
    ~test() {} //<-----Run the program once with and once without this line.
};

int main()
{
    test x;
    test *a(&x);
    cout << "a before memory allocation: " << a << endl;
    a = new test;
    cout << "a after memory allocation and before delete: " << a << endl;
    delete a;
    cout << "a after delete: " << a << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

With default destructor the result is:
[image]
But with my own destructor it's:
[image]
Isn't the second result erroneous? Because somewhere I read that:

> the deallocation function shall deallocate the storage referenced by the pointer, **rendering invalid all pointers referring to any part of the deallocated storage**.

Maybe I'm not following it correctly(especially due to the difficult English words used!). Would you please explain to me why is this happening?
**What's exactly the difference between my simply defined destructor and the C++ default destructor?** 
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: The fact that the pointer remains the same does not contradict the fact that the storage is deallocated. This is memory that could be re-used and it would be your own fault to access this memory using the pointer you just deleted.

Comment: @Gerriet Would you give an example? Thank you.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the pointer modification with default destructor: http://ideone.com/vg3TYD

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @JVApen I think it's the Microsoft compiler, I'm using VS-2015.

Comment: Are you sure this is the entire program? The only way to get those results is with undefined behavior, but I don't see anything that would cause undefined behavior.

Comment: None of the behavior decribed in the question has anything to do with the way the destructor is defined.

Comment: Do the results change if you switch between Debug and Release modes?

Comment: @MarkRansom No. I tested it but the problem exists yet.

Comment: @AnT Would you please explain it a bit more? I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `a` is a (non-null) pointer to an object, then operation `delete a` triggers the destructor of the object to which `a` is pointing to (the default destructor or a specific one) and finally frees the memory that had been allocated for this object. The memory to which `a` has pointed is not a valid object any more, and `a` must not be dereferenced any more. However, `delete a` does not set the value of pointer `a` back to a specific value. Actually I'm surprised that `delete a` in your case changed the value of `a`; I cannot reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: Some compilers like Visual Studio for debug mode will set the pointer to an invalid value after deletion to help identify dereferencing of invalid addresses.